# Request params do not contain proper values

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm using Mongoose to build a REST API using NodeJs and am running into issues with the params of req.

The code I'm using (model) is as follows:

```
'use strict';
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
var Schema = mongoose.Schema; 

var RequestSchema = new Schema({
    query: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    number: {
        type: String, 
        default: ''
    }, 
    subject: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Cel', RequestSchema)
```

However, when I use the following code from my controller (answerQuery is used for a POST request) and print out the values I find unexpected values :

```
exports.answerQuery = function(req, res) {
    console.log('query is : ' + req.params.query); // this is undefined
    console.log('query is : ' + req.body.query); // this is the value of query
    console.log('query is: ' + req.params.number); // this is the value of number
    console.log('subject is : ' + req.params.subject); // this is undefined 
};
```

I understand why `req.body.query` works but am confused as to why `req.params.query` and `req.params.subject` don't work (return undefined) but `req.params.number` does. I haven't used Javascript a lot and think that I might be missing something here.

Edit 0: I'm using a POST request for this

Edit 1: This is my route file:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(app) {
    var celRequest = require('../controllers/celSearchController'); 

    // Routes 
    app.route('/celsearch/:number')
        .post(celRequest.answerQuery);
};
```

Comment: is there a url associated with your answerQuery route? If so, can you include that?

Comment: If answerQuery is your POST request then you will be getting your data in req.body not in req.query.   req.query or req.params is used for GET request

Comment: Can you show the POST request url along with params and their values.?

Comment: @UditKumawat that makes sense since I'm using a POST request. I'll edit the question to reflect that. Could you go ahead and answer it so that I can mark it as the correct answer. Also why would req.params.number work then while the others don't?   
Thanks!

Comment: You should post the route handler that is calling `answerQuery`, it may shed some light on why this is happening.

Comment: @robertklep I added it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route is this:

```
POST /celsearch/:number
```

This defines one parameter, `number`. Parameters are accessed through `req.params`, which is why `req.params.number` works.

You are trying to access `req.params.subject`, referring to a parameter called `subject`, which doesn't exist. Therefore, it's undefined. Same goes for `req.params.query`.

Because it's a POST route, and it's most common to pass data to POST routes using the request body, that data ends up in `req.body`. Since the client is passing a parameter called *"query"* in the request body, `req.body.query` works.

So:

- `req.params` is used for route parameters, the `:NAME` placeholders in the route declaration;
- `req.body` is used for parameters passed in the request body, commonly used for `POST` requests;
- `req.query` is used for parameters passed in the URL as a query string: `/foo/bar?query=somevalue`. This is generally used for `GET` requests.